# Autoplaying next html5 <audio> when previous element ends

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am a javascript newbie and have generated page of audio elements and would like them to autoplay in sequence - ie have the audio element automatically start playing when the previous one ends.

I managed to get the second element in the page to automatically play after any random element is played in Firefox, but thats as far as I got.

I would like to have:

1. the current audio element+1 play (instead of always the second element);
2. then play each subsequent element until the rest of the list (following the current element) have been played.

My code at present is:

```
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
          if(audios[i] != e.target){
              audios[i].pause();
          } else { 
            audios[i].addEventListener('ended', function(e){
                audios[(i+1)%len].play();
            })
          };

     }
}, true);
```

I tried to put some of the code into a function that I can call recursively (unfortunately I deleted the code because I got stuck) but the basic idea would be something like this:

```
// function playNextAudioElementAndAddEndedListener(audios[n]) {
//    audios[n].play()
//    audios[n].addEventListener('ended', function(e){
//       var n = n+1
//       playNextAudioAndAddEndedListener(audioElement[n])
//    })
//   }


document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
          if(audios[i] != e.target){
              audios[i].pause();
          } else { 
            audios[i].addEventListener('ended', function(e){
                // playNextAudioElementAndAddEndedListener(audios[(i+1)%len])
                })
            })
          };
      }
    }, true);
```

Got it working thanks to Gabriel Martin. I've implemented it like this:

```
document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
      var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
      for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++){
            if(audios[i] != e.target){
                audios[i].pause();
            }
      };
      setup();
    }, true);

    function setup() {
      const audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

      for (let i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
          audios[i].addEventListener('ended', () => {
              audios[(i + 1) % audios.length].play();
          });
      }
    }
```

Comment: That piece of code seems to be running inside an event listener. Could you please provide more context? Also, please try and be more careful with code indentation, it makes it so much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Also, most browsers won't allow audio to play except as a result of a *user-initiated* event (tap, click, ...). The ```ended``` event is not user initiated, so that could explain the behavior you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for your response I accidentally left out the first and last line. I have amended it. The first audio play is user initiated and I have managed to get it to then play the second (absolute) element when the first clicked element plays.

Comment: Maybe a better place to call the setup function is when the DOM is ready, because in the current way, the code will add new eventListeners to the "ended" event each time the "play" event is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function setup() {
    const audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

    for (let i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
        audios[i].addEventListener('ended', () => {
            audios[(i + 1) % audios.length].play();
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You just need to call "setup();" when all elements are ready.